# Count incremental blank cells till next non empty cell (Formulas Only)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data looks like below. I want to count consecutive blank cells till next non empty cell. My logic is to get output, when `A2` contains data then it will return `0` but when `A3` is blank then I expect `1` and continue to count blank cells incrementally.

```
Part_No Location    Expected_Output
ABC123  North          0
        South          1
XYZ123  East           0
        South          1
        West           2
PQR123  South          0
        East           1
        North          2
        West           3
BROF-2  South          0
        East           1
```

***Screenshot as well***
[image]

***Hope someone will help me to solve my problem. Thanks.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Range C2, use the formula:

```
=IF($A2<>"",0,$C1+1)
```

and then copy down- should do the trick.

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: Its really easy but hard to catch. Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this if the blanks are in coulmn A

```
 =COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("A"&LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:A2<>""),ROW($A$2:A2))&":A"&ROW()))
```

Comment: Your formula also works for me. Thanks for your effort.