# Excel: Count consecutive cells that are not empty

Tags: excel, match, blank-line

I would like to identify which rows don't have consecutive data. For this, I'd like to be able to count the cells across rows until and empty cell is encountered.

Please look at the the screenshot of an example and desired output.
[image]

I have tried to play around with the MATCH function, but no look yet. I've tried the following but it's not returning what I would've expect.

```
{=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(C2:F2),0)}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41782852/4961700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try in this way however there might be a more eloquent way to solve this,

So the formula used in cell **G2**

```
    =IF(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(C2:F2,COLUMN(C2:F2)),
IF(C2:F2=FALSE,COLUMN(C2:F2))))<3,"Jumps A Year",
MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(C2:F2,COLUMN(C2:F2)),
IF(C2:F2=FALSE,COLUMN(C2:F2)))))
```

And **Fill Down!**

Also note, depending on your excel version you may or may need to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, not just `ENTER` after entering the formula. You will know the array is active when you see `curly braces { }` appear around your formula.

[image: Count consecutive cells that are not empty]

Comment: Did you see this in the link I gave? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41783089/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, i saw, but there is no such solution which matches with this query and solves the query of OP!